# Showing random data from core-data using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, random

I need some help getting random data from core data using Swift 3, Xcode 8.3.1. I currently have an app that creates a list in tableview using data that is entered by the user.. (user enters a name and takes a picture of that person) The entity "Friend" holds the attributes "name", "image".

The first version of this app was just a name and I would use arc4random to randomly update a label with a name on a modally presented VC on a button click. The names were simply stored in an Array.
 This version is including an image so I decided to try my hand at core-data (never used it before) and now I'm stuck at my random select button. Currently the app will store the data fine and then retrieve it and display everyone alphabetically along with their image in a tableview. As a new person is submitted the info gets stored and the tableview updates.

I need to show a randomly selected name and its image, but I don't know how to do this and research has failed me on getting it done.

If there is a better way of storing an image & name instead of core-data I'm open to changing as well. The app stores anywhere from 20-80 different names. It will never be used to store much more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch your items from the context, which will give you an array of objects. Now you just use your favorite random function to get a random index for this array. And then use an object at that index.

Comment: Sounds like a great plan. How do I execute this in Swift code :)  I'm very fresh to coding and have no idea how to implement what you just said.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't seem to get formatting to work :(

    func randomImage() -> MyImage? {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MyImage>(entityName: "MyImage")
    var images : Array<MyImage> = []
    do {
    images = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    return nil
    }
    guard images.count > 0 else {
    return nil
    }
    let randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(images.count)
    return images[arc4random_uniform(images.count)];
    }